# Apply limit in mapreduce function in php?

Tags: php, mongodb

How to apply limit in `php, mongodb` when using `mapreduce` function?
I tried this

```
$cmd=array(// codition array
"mapreduce" => "user", 
"map" => $map,
"reduce" => $reduce,
"out" => array("inline" => 1),
"limit"=>2
);

$db=connect();
$query = $db->command($cmd);// run command
```

But its not working it gives 2 documents.I can't use limit on sub documents.
If I have 100's of sub documents and then I want paging in sub documents.Then it fails.Is it possible to apply limit on sub documents?

Answer (score 0):

In your query you can use $slice: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields . However you won't be able to paginate your suboducment inside of your MR if that's what your asking.

I am not sure what you by "Then it fails". So I cannot give a reliable answer there.

By the way, limit works on the root documents only. Subdocuments are merely arrays within your root document, not entirely separate tables.